# How can I know it is safe to call vkFreeMemory?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to update a model in my Vulkan rendered scene (with a new mesh that has a different number of nodes, for example), and want to clear the data held in buffers, like so (inside  a Model class, where `device` and `vertices` are members, `device` is a `VkDevice` and `vertices.memory` is a `VkDeviceMemory`):

```
            if (vertices.buffer)
            {
                vkDestroyBuffer(device, vertices.buffer, nullptr);
                vkFreeMemory(device, vertices.memory, nullptr);
                vertices.buffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
                vertices.memory = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
            }
```

But will get occasional errors like this, telling me that the memory is in use by a command buffer:

```
ERROR: [1214025378][VUID-vkFreeMemory-memory-00677] : Validation Error: [ VUID-vkFreeMemory-memory-00677 ] Object 0: handle = 0x23b81794958, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x485c8ea2 | Cannot call vkFreeMemory on VkDeviceMemory 0x7e08100000002e4f[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to memory (via images or buffers) must have completed execution (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.154.1/windows/1.2-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkFreeMemory-memory-00677)
```

And eventually crash.
My draw call uses a fence to wait for the queue to be completed - but I am clearly missing another synchronisation step before I try to vkFreeMemory.
How can I make this vkFreeMemory safe(r)?

Comment: Broadly speaking, a single model shouldn't have its own device memory. Models should share allocated memory by using sub-sections of a single allocation. Ideally, the number of allocations you make should not scale linearly with the complexity of the scene.

Comment: That’s interesting! More fun for me later.. but I guess the original question still applies, unless you only ever clear memory on shutdown?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Seems that you just clearly need to fix the sync? Nothing much we can help with except start talking how to generally debug code.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if there are additional measures I can take to "fix the sync", I think I am onto something with pipeline barriers